# replace bookmarks in text file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

We have a bunch of emails that need to be code-generate using data stored in database. Body for emails are stored in an XML file (could be moved to json or table). I like to use some sort of bookmarks (created using their corresponding table/field name) and then populate them.

For example:

```
*Good day:
This is the initial communication to a <<**order_no**>>, please ensure the communication 
is consistent through this thread.

Please find herein links to business requirements for: <<**project_name**>>
BR # <<**br_no**>>
PRJ # <<**project_no**>>*
```

1. How do I read the XML file?
2. How do I manipulate the text?

Thank you!

Comment: If the XML is in a file, you would use something like `file_get_contents`. To replace strings, `str_replace` or `strtr` would work. This is all basic PHP, nothing CakePHP-specific about it.

Comment: Use `str_replace` to replace the placeholder with value you provide.

Comment: also catch placeholders that were not resolved, replace them with empty string `'/\[([0-9a-zA-Z_]*?(?=-)*)\]/'`